# Zooming UIImageView inside UIScrollView causes UIImageView frame aspect ratio change.

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `UIScrollView` and I would like the user to be able to zoom in on the image. So far, the zooming works, but I began noticing some extra space in the scroll view's `contentSpace`. Initially, I thought this was due to `contentOffset` issues or the like, but after debugging I discovered that aspect ratio of the image view changes after zooming. Initially, the image view fits the image, but, after zooming, the aspect ratio of the image view becomes square. Since the viewed image is rectangular, there is some extra space in the image view. How can this be fixed?